# Polymer 1.0 <iron-ajax> inside of a dom-repeat

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am trying to use

`<template is="dom-repeat" as="plugin" items="{{plugins}}">`

to loop through an array of objects, and then for each of the objects in this array generate a url to fetch data from. This data I want to then put into the page.

My element looks like this:

```html
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<script src="../../scripts/plugins.js"></script>

<dom-module id="sidenav-list">
 <template>
  <template is="dom-repeat" as="plugin" items="{{plugins}}">
   <template is="dom-if" if="{{plugin.sidenav}}">
    <iron-ajax auto url="{{_generatePluginUrl(plugin)}}" handle-as="text" last-response="{{plugin.ajax}}"></iron-ajax>
    <html-echo html="{{plugin.ajax}}"></html-echo>
   </template>
  </template>
 </template>
 <script>
  Polymer({
   is: 'sidenav-list',
   ready: function() {
    this.plugins = allAddons();
   },
   _generatePluginUrl: function(plugin) {
    var newURL = "./plugins/" + plugin.folder + "/" + plugin.file;
    return newURL;
   },
  });
 </script>
</dom-module>
```

The problem is that is I set `last-response="pluginAjax"` I end up with duplicates, and when I set it to `plugin.ajax` the result is just undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation (via the comments) -- linking here because the documentation viewer does not allow linking directly to the dom-repeat doc page.

https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/0f8483da48dc3747f3c4bdd439b95c4bce2897d7/src/lib/template/dom-repeat.html#L59s

You can achieve this goal by using

```
event.model.set('item.ajax, event.detail.response)
```

in your on-response handler's function.

ie:
if your iron-ajax looked like this:

```
<iron-ajax auto url="{{_generatePluginUrl(plugin)}}" handle-as="text"
           on-response="_hresponse"></iron-ajax>
```

Then your handler in your element would look like:

```
Polymer({
    //...
    _hresponse: function(request){
        request.model.set('plugin.ajax', request.detail.response);
    }
});
```